# Making a String into an SKNode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have the correct SKNODE in String Format.  I want to transform the String Name "A2Square" Into the NODE called A2Square.

Is this possible?

Is there anyway to take the String "A2Square" And somehow transform it into an SKNODE with the same name....

Comment: I am confused as well, WHAT do you want to do / change? The "`name`"??? Like variable name, or image name???

Comment: I have the correct SKNODE in String Format.  I want to convert the String NAME into the SKNODE.  Is this possible?

Comment: Are you looking for `childNodeWithName("A2Square")`?

Comment: Would probably help if you read the SKNode documentation. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKNode_Ref/

Comment: do you want to DISPLAY a string? as a node?

Comment: Do you want to create an `SKNode` instance named "A2Square" from a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is not entirely clear to me what you are trying to do, you are probably looking for [SKLabelNode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKLabelNode_Ref/). This is a special node which can be rendered as text (a label).

Some sample code:

```
SKLabelNode *winner = [SKLabelNode labelNodeWithFontNamed:@"Chalkduster"];
winner.text = @"A2Square";
winner.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.bounds),
                              CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds));
[self addChild:winner];
```